# LineChart does not sort XYChart.Series when new data is added

Tags: charts, javafx-2, linechart

I have implemented a ListChangeListener to an ObservableList, from where I add new data to a XYChart.Series that is used in a LineChart (see picture).

[image: XYSeries of LineChart is not sorted]

However, if I add new data to the series of the StackedAreaChart it is properly sorted, whereas the LineChart does display the single elements of the series according to their position within the series.

I have already tried to sort the ObservableList via FXCollection after I have added new elements to the series in the listener, but this does only lead to an exception (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added).

Can anybody provide me a proper solution or is this problem not solved before JDK8?